# Anyone know a good tool for validating XHTML/CSS offline?

Tags: css, xhtml

I'd like to find a command-line tool for Linux that will validate both XHTML and CSS. As silly as this may sound, I'd like it to be able to operate offline.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### [HTML tidy](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/) is a great tool for X/HTML validation

- There is a [Windows GUI available for tidy](http://pagesperso-orange.fr/ablavier/TidyGUI/).
- Tidy's [sourceforge page is here](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/).
- For plain-old XHTML or XML validation you can use any XML editor with a validator. Or a simple tool like [xmlstartlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/).

#### [The W3C's CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/DOWNLOAD.html) is also available for download

#### [This tool](http://people.tuke.sk/igor.podlubny/oc.html) claims to do offline CSS validation

Comment: Tidy is great, but I need a tool for CSS as well.

Comment: Thanks, I had heard the W3C CSS validator could be run offline, but the link that I found previously was to a version that didn't work.

Comment: What I have done in the past as a last-resort for CSS validation was to upload my CSS to the W3C site. I know that doesn't help when you have no internet - but it is a good enough solution when you are working with files that are on an intranet.

Answer (score 0):

HTML Tidy is the defacto tool for this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of Tidy: http://tidy.sourceforge.net/.